# Type inference lost inner level types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In the below code example, I can't figure out why `FinalType` is `{ test: { test_inner: any } }`. I don't know where the `any` is come from (and `string` is lost). Meanwhile, `test` has the right return type of `{ test_inner: string }`

```
interface IAction {
    type: string;
}

type Reducer<S> = (state: S, action: IAction) => S

function combineReducers<S>(reducers: { [K in keyof S]: Reducer<S[K]> }): Reducer<S> {
    const dummy = {} as S;
    return () => dummy;
}

const test_inner = (test: string, action: IAction) => {
    return 'dummy';
}
const test = combineReducers({
    test_inner
});

const test_outer = combineReducers({
    test
});

type FinalType = ReturnType<typeof test_outer>;
```

I am in the process of typing my redux application. But I think the problem is not specific to redux. I am well aware of `@types/redux` but I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in how TypeScript shows back the type to you - logged https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23897

The *real* type of `FinalType` is actually correct; it's just a display bug.